# Find the general solution for the diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\frac{d f(x)}{dx}=-cf(x)+g(x)$. 
I need to prove that the general solution for this differential equation is:
$$f(x)=f(0)e^{-cx}+\int_0^xe^{-c(x-y)}g(y)dy$$
with c constant.

Comment: Solve for homogenous solution, then try an integrating factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first remark that the proposed solution $f(x)=f(0)e^{-cx}...$ depends on an arbitrary constant $f(0)$, thus is a candidate for being the general solution.

This function, written under the form:

$$f(x)=f(0)e^{-cx}+e^{-cx}h(x) \ \ \text{where} \ \ h(x):=\int_0^xe^{cy}g(y)dy$$

yields, by multiplying by $e^{cx}$

$$e^{cx}f(x)=f(0)+h(x)$$

Differentiationg it, and because $h$ is a primitive function of $e^{cx}g(x)$:

$$ce^{cx}f(x)+e^{cx}f'(x)=e^{cx}g(x)$$

i.e., by multiplying by multiplying by $e^{-cx}$, we obtain the initial differential equation.